# Using ldap memberof in phpldapadmin

Tags: php, ubuntu, ldap, phpldapadmin

Unless im not using it properly which is probable, but I am using ldap query clause member-of to find members of a group ou here is the code below:

```
ldap_set_option($conn,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);

$searchText= "ou=Aston University,dc=blackboard,dc=com";
$regdn = "memberof=$searchText";

$regfilter = "cn=$searchText*";
$nodes = array("cn","street","mail","uidNumber");

$searchRead = ldap_search($conn,$regdn,$regfilter,$nodes);
$en = ldap_get_entries($conn,$searchRead);
```

and i seem to be getting zero entries when they are numerous entries. What am i doing wrong?